# Why does Blender not update the screen properly, despite not lagging?

Tags: modeling

Whenever I do something (for example use the mouse wheel to zoom in or out) I need to press another key for my initial action to be recorded and updated. It is really frustrating and I can not work like this, being an absolute beginner with 3D modeling and animations.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That's odd.. What OS/gpu/specs?

Comment: I think this is a bug. This has happened to me before, but only with transforms, and I think it was because I had a recursive parenting structure. Maybe you have some problematic rig?

Comment: Isn't that the same as looped parents?

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that you are looking for the "Release Confirms" option in the "Editing" tab of the "User Preferences" window.
[image]

Comment: That would not affect zooming, only transforms.